# Meaning of the name of the movie Clash of the Titans?

Tags: title, clash-of-the-titans-2010, wrath-of-the-titans

I've seen [*Immortals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortals_(2011_film)) and from there I come to know who the Titans were. And in [*Clash of the Titans*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clash_of_the_Titans_(2010_film)), they also showed that Zeus and Hades etc. killed Titans and became gods.

After watching the movie I didn't understand what the meaning of the name is. Where is the clash of Titans? What exactly does it mean and how is it related to the story of the movie?

(same for the [*Wrath of the Titans*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrath_of_the_Titans))

Answer (score 1):

The Titans of the title are not the literal Titans of Greek mythology (giants born of Uranus and Gaea). The term as used is the generic 'titan,' meaning ["one that is gigantic in size or power."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/titan)

The Stygian witches in the film refer to the Kraken and Medusa as titans.

Comment: @Siraj Using a movie like Immortals as a source for your knowledge of what Titans are is also a poor idea.  If you want to know about mythological characters it is better to look up a reference about those mythological characters in stead of depending on a movie for information you hope is accurate.

Comment: I'm not just depending on that movie for my facts. I have also searched a lot and found the similarity in all the movies. Still didn't give the answer of my question.

Answer (score 0):

### Clash

When used as a noun, clash [can be defined as a violent or sharp conflict](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clash). The movie *Clash of the Titans* refers to a violent conflict between the Titans and the Olympians. The preposition "of" does not necessarily mean "between" as you seem to be implying.

In other words, saying clash of the titans doesn't necessarily mean it was a clash *between* titans.

### Wrath

Wrath as a noun has [two potentially pertinent definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrath) in context of the movie *Wrath of the Titans*.

1. strong vengeful anger or indignation
2. retributory punishment for an offense or a crime : **divine chastisement**

The plot of *Wrath* includes the Titans striking back in retribution for the events of the first film. Kronos himself makes an appearance in attacking the army of Andromeda with Ares.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. Clash of the Titans refers to Medusa vs. the Kraken. Medusa’s head is used to kill the Kraken- hence the Stygian witches saying “A Titan against a Titan!” Or Clash of the Titans.

Answer (score -1):

[Titans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(mythology)), by definition, include Hades, Zeus, Poseidon, etc...

The main conflict in the movie is between Hades and Perseus, since Perseus is more or less the defender of humans and just so happens to be the son of Zeus, who tricked Hades into being the lord of the underworld.

The "clash", therefore, is between Hades and Zeus, who are both Titans and who have different opinions as to what they want from mortals.  Zeus wants admiration and reverence, Hades is more content to have their fear.  In a "see this from 30,000 feet" aspect, Hades is pitting his Kraken against Zeus' son, in an epic battle to see who will control the mortals.

Comment: In the link given by you have defined 12 titans. Oceanus and Tethys,
Hyperion and Theia,
Coeus and Phoebe,
Cronus and Rhea,
Mnemosyne, Themis,
Crius, Iapetus

That doesn't include Zeus or Hades. Zeus and Hades are the sons of Cronus which is one of the 12 titans.

Comment: Read it a little closer.  Zeus, Poseidon and Hades are definitely there.

Comment: Zeus, Hades, and Poseidon are gods, not titans.